# jquery tablesorter duplicating rows after .trigger('sorton', [dynamicSorting])

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

According to [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3722646/1936024) I used  `.trigger('update')` and also applied  `.trigger('sorton', [dynamicSorting]);` according to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eY8uH/1559/).

The sorting works fine, but it is duplicating rows and prepending it to table.

all my table html is dynamic, and I am appending it like.

```
$('table.table tbody, table.table thead').empty(); // This was added later to remove existing rows.
$("#success_table_id").html(successful_html);
$("#failure_table_id").html(failure_html);
$("#manual_table_id").html(manual_html);
```

I know this is not enough info, but hoping that somebody has already faced this and sorted it out.

**Note : I am having tablesorter 2.0.5.**

Answer (score 2):

The original tablesorter does not provide a callback after the update has completed so your best bet would be to use a `setTimeout` to trigger a resort ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1561/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter();

$('button').click(function() {
    var tbl = '<tr>...</tr>';
    var sorting = $('table')[0].config.sortList;

    $('table').find('tbody').html(tbl);
    $('table').trigger('update');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('table').trigger('sorton', [sorting]);
    }, 200);
});
```

If you use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), it will automatically resort the content, if the [`resort` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#resort) is set to `true` (default setting) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/1560/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    sortList: [[1,0]],
    resort: true
});

$('button').click(function() {
    var tbl = '<tr>...</tr>';
    $('table')
        .find('tbody')
        .html(tbl)
        .trigger('update');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Mottie, It did remove duplicate rows, but sorting on click of column header do not work after adding rows dynamically.

Comment: No luck, Does table HTML need some specific structure?